# Forum Data Analysis

Tags: forum, expert-system, information-extraction

I'm working on an expert system that analysing data from a Forum and get some trustable  informations , then i'm using these information to learn my expert system .

The question is How to extract data that give me 90% trustable data if only about 50% of existing data on the forum is true ?! and what is the best resources about forum data extraction ??

I searched a lot about this topic but i've got nothing ,mainly because of its bad keyword "forum" !!

thank you

Comment: Given that 'forum data' could be anything, in any format, this is not a real question.

Comment: We are willing to help, but need more clarification about your problem.It often helps if you can structure your question/question-statement to be more specific. -- so what kind of data (type and format) are you dealing with, and what kinds of info / patterns do you wish to learn from it? That might be a good place to start.

Comment: I wonder how you got the 50% figure. If you know so precisely how much of the info is true, then how come you don't know what part of it is true?